# Ошибка Vk_Bot при получении сообщения от пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Пишу значит я vkbot, только учусь поэтом код с habr.Код работает без ошибок, но когда приходит от юзера сообщение выдает ошибку:

```
  File "F:/Программирование/Python/Vk_Bot/vk_bot.py", line 20, in <module>
    write_msg(event.user_id,'Всё пучком')    File "F:/Программирование/Python/Vk_Bot/vk_bot.py", line 6, in write_msg
    vk.method('message.send',{'user_id': user_id,'message': message})#вывоз метода сообщений   File "C:\Users\Aleksey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [3] 
Unknown method pass
```

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

#функкция приема сообщения
def write_msg(user_id,message):#функция которая принимает id пользователь и сообщение пользователя
    vk.method('message.send',{'user_id': user_id,'message': message})#вывоз метода сообщений

token = ""#токен бота
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)# подключаемся к классу VkAPi и даем доступ к токену
longpool = VkLongPoll(vk)#работа с сообщения
#aut = vk.auth()

for event in longpool.listen():#подключаем метод .listen() - слушать сервер
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:#VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW получения сообщения с api
        if event.to_me:
            request = event.text
            if request == "Привет":
                write_msg(event.user_id,'Хай')
            else:
                write_msg(event.user_id,'Всё пучком')
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет метода `message.send`, скорее всего, Вы опечатались и имели в виду `messages.send` (во мн. ч.).

Но с методом ещё не всё, Вы также пропустили аргумент `random_id`, который необходим для отправки сообщения.

---

Насчёт самого кода, Вы используете неправильный модуль — для работы с чат-ботами Вам необходим `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.

Для отправки сообщений рекомендуется использовать `peer_id` — универсальный идентификатор и для бесед, и для личных сообщений.

А для удобного взаимодействия с `API` можно получить `Python`-объект через метод `get_api()`.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


vk_session = VkApi(token='[access_token]')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '[group_id]')
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=get_random_id(),
                peer_id=event.obj['peer_id'],
                message='Test message',
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```